# Audio Sound not playing in the Firebox using AudioContext

Tags: angular, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

using the  WebAudio API  AudioContext. its working fine in the chrome and playing sounds. but its not playing sound in the firefox, showing icon in the bar of playing audio.

```
// console.log("this.audioContext.state", this.audioContext.state);

//create buffer source node which is used to play a sound one time
const bufferSourceNode = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
// bufferSourceNode.channelCount = 1;
// bufferSourceNode.channelCountMode
console.log('Created buffer source node');
//set buffer to one of the loaded sounds;
bufferSourceNode.buffer = sound;
//connect to output
bufferSourceNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
//play the sound
bufferSourceNode.start();
//stop the sound
// bufferSourceNode.stop(this.audioContext.currentTime + 0.5);
//end  the sound
bufferSourceNode.onended = () => {
console.log("onended");
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate a simple sample in stackblitz?

Comment: @wannadream currently using the token for the authentication,url  made from the raw files pcm file. and converted the arraybuffer to the audio buffer by using this code . this is creating issue in firefox for not playing sound

const myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(2, audioCtx.sampleRate * 2, audioCtx.sampleRate);
        myArrayBuffer.copyToChannel(buffer, 0,1);

Comment: From the doc, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createBuffer, your code should work as it is designated. If there is an issue, you may need to report an bug to Mozilla, I think.